# how to position two divs next to each other, one of them is centered in the container of both divs

Tags: css, html

how to position two divs next to each other, one of them is centered in the container of both divs

How can I position the second div directly next to the first one and make it expand to the right side ?

here is an example :

http://jsfiddle.net/Dpcq4/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="container" >
    <div id="div1"> </div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  #container{ width: 100%;
              display:inline;
              height:60px;
              color:#000;
    }
    #div1{ margin-left:auto;
           margin-right:auto;
           width:200px;
           height:50px;
           background-color:#333;
    }
    #div2{ float:right;
           width:100%;
           height:50px;
           background-color:#ccc;
    }
```

thanks.

Comment: So you want the first div to center and have the second div take up the space to the right. Is that correct?

Comment: yes exactly     |DIV1CENTERED|DIV2-----expand-------|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/GTduj/2/

```
#container{ 
    width: 600px; 
    height:60px; 
    border:1px solid #bbb;
    text-align:center;
}
```

You need a fixed width for your container element, and you want to center it's contents.

```
#div1{        
    width:60%;
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;     
    background-color:#333; 
}
```

div1 could be a % width or fixed, but it needs to be inline-block.

```
#div2{        
    display:inline-block;
     width:10%; 
    height:50px; 
    background-color:#ccc; 
    margin-right:0;    
    position:absolute;    
}
```

Use inline-block and absolute position for div2 and so it will hang off after your centered div1.

Comment: I used  width:200px on div1 ( it should be fixed)
and 100% width for the 2nd div .. then i got exactly what i was looking for.

thanks for your help. and for sure for everyones answer too :D

Comment: here is the code i used .. need some hack for IE but it is working :
http://jsfiddle.net/GTduj/5/

Answer (score 0):

just give `float:left` to your `div1` and make sure this:

```
width(div1) + width(div2) <= width(Screen)
```

so, you want the `div2` to take rest of the space, so give both the divs percentage width i.e.
give div1 30% width, and div2 70% width.

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/Dpcq4/8/)

## Update:

so you want the `div1` to always be at the center of the `#container`, then give it `left:50%` and accordingly adjust the `div2`

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/Dpcq4/14/) if that is what you want.

Comment: div1 is not centered. this is the problem. it should keep its centered position and width.

Answer (score 0):

Centering a div within another div with          margin: auto implies you are taking the whole width of the containing div. Put div1 within another div that you give a specified width, then float div1 in it.

```
<div id="container" >
  <div class="container">
    <div id="div1"> </div>
  </div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
</div>

.container{
  width: x%;
  float: left;
 }

#div2{
 float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want white space on the left you need to remove `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` from `#div1.` Also you need to change `#div2` width.

Something like this:

```
#div1{
    width:200px; 
    height:50px; 
    background-color:#333; 
    float:left;
}
#div2{
    width:75%; 
    height:50px; 
    background-color:#ccc; 
    margin-right:0; 
    float:left;
}
```

However if this is meant to be fluid I would change `#div1` width to a percentage as well. Something like `width:25%;`; If you intend to have white space to the left of the two divs then you would need to add div to the left to act as a column.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dpcq4/12/

Comment: this is the problem., div1 should keep its centered position and width.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the ways I know to do this. Maybe someone else can inform us both of a better way.

First, hard coding the widths in your css like this

```
#container{ 
    width: 600px; 
    height:60px; 
    color:#000;
}
#div1{
    float: left;
    width:200px; 
    height:50px; 
    background-color:#333; 
    margin-left: 200px;
}
#div2{
    float:left; 
    width:200px; 
    height:50px; 
    background-color:#ccc; 
    margin-right:0;
}
```

If this isn't an options, and I'm sure it probably wont be, another solution will be using javascript. I'll be using jquery in the example.

```
var container = $('#container1');
var div1 = $('#div1');

div1.css('margin-left', container.width()/2-div1.width());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dpcq4/9/

Answer (score 0):

My method works in ie8 and above along with all other browsers and uses strictly css.
By using display:table and then display:table-cell for it's children it keeps the two elements in the same table row.

```
#container{ 
   width: 100%; 
   display:table; 
   height:60px; 
   color:#000;
}
#div1{
   margin-left:auto; 
   margin-right:auto; 
   width:200px; 
   height:50px; 
   background-color:#333;
   display:table-cell; 
}
#div2{
   display:table-cell;
   height:50px; 
   background-color:#ccc; 
   margin-right:0;
   float:left;
   width:100%; 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dpcq4/13/